# Making nav-bar/menu responsive with browser

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Case</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
<img src="Logo.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon" width="250" height="80">
</div>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="/index.php">  <br><br>      Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/page2.php">Game</a></li>
<li><a href="/page3.php">Whats Yours</a></li>
<li><a href="/page4.php"><br>Profits</a></li>
<li><a href="/page5.php"><br>Proof</a></li>
<li><a href="/page6.php"><br>Getting<br> Started</a></li>
<li><a href="/page7.php"><br><br>About Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

I have this header/menu navbar, on my computer its a straight bar that display home, game,..etc. however I realized on my phone when I open it, the menu becomes a list downwards, for example:

```
Home
Game
Whats yours
etc
```

How can I make it responsive with the browser therefore it would stay in a straight line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

It will make them to stay inline. and remove the `<br>` from all menu items

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/KgrrzX)**

```
.nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```